# Linux C GCC interrupt by another process

Tags: php, c, linux, gcc

I am trying to write a program that accesses a MYSQL database. The database is used by a PHP Script and the C program.

My C program is in a sleep mode most of the time and needs to be informed if something is changed by the PHP script in the database. Therefor I wanted to call a little process which sends an interrupt to my C program, which then connects to the database and downloads the changes.

The database connection and everything else is working fine. But I have no idea how to realize this interrupt, and I dont want to simply poll my database.

Has anyone an advice for me?

Comment: Yout MySQL DB does not support triggers that can generate external events?  Most DB can, and you can then use a suitable inter-process synchro, eg. a semaphore, to notify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a signal which you send with `posix_kill` from php and receive it with a signal handler installed with `signal` from your C code. However, you will probably have to run you C program as the same user running your web server for php being allowed to send signals to your C process.

Comment: Thank you thats what i needed

Answer (score 0):

This is already an extremely odd thing to want to do and you are likely misrepresenting the actual problem. Why the thing modifying the database is not the same thing doing the work, whatever it is? If the work needs to be done relatively quickly, you may just want to sleep for n seconds before checking out if there is anything new to do. If requests are rare and you need fast reaction anyway, you want to have something like a unix socket. The C program (why is the code in C?) would wait on the socket and notifications sent over the socket would prompt it to query the database. Except why would you make it query the database? Why not send the actual request?

Comment: The code is in c because i use i2c to communicate with some hardware. I am using a database, because there is very much data to be handled, which i think is simpler with a Database. Thank you i am trying it with Sockets or Signal :)

Comment: This does not explain why would you talk with the database from the C program. You can have a wrapper which does all necessary handling and a C program shoveling the data through i2c. And your reply still does not answer why would you use a database, let alone mysql. Also signals are a terrible interface for this.